# Flexslider - navigation arrow hide until hover

Tags: javascript, flexslider

Currently using Flexslider and would like to be able to hide the navigation arrows which presently appear on right and left side of the image but than have them appear when the user hovers over the image. I remember it being addressed on the old site - muffin one, but cannot find it on woothemes.
Does anyone have an idea on how to change/modify/add info to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the arrows in the css.  If you want the arrows to always be visible you want to change the opacity.  It's currently set to 0 which makes it non-visible until hover (the hover opacity is set to 1 which is completely visible).  So you want to just make it visible like so:

```
.flex-direction-nav a {opacity: 1;}
```

If you then want to change the location of the arrow you will need to simply change the margin.  It is currently set to -20px.  If you want to make it appear outside the box you will need to make it something like this:

```
.flex-direction-nav a {margin: -40px 0 0;}
```

If you did both your css would look like this:

```
.flex-direction-nav a {opacity: 1; margin: -40px 0 0;}
```

This would make your arrows always be visible and appear outside the image (to the right and left of the image instead of on top of the image).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably accomplish this via jQuery.  In my case I am using FlexSlider for Drupal so I cannot promise that you will have the same CSS selectors, but I hope this code could provide a general idea :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("div.flexslider").hover(function() {
                            $("a.prev").show();
                            $("a.next").show();
                        },
                        function() {
                            $("a.prev").hide();
                            $("a.next").hide();
                        });})
```

Good Luck!

P.S.  I forgot to mention that you should set your a tag selectors in your CSS to display:none; by default.